# Как задать рамки или границы для кнопок?

Tags: android

Здесь представлены 6 кнопок. Они прижаты к друг-другу. Как показать их границы (или поставить рамки тонкой черной линией)? Тогда пользователю было бы более понятно и приложение выглядело бы более красиво.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вбиваем в гугл

   > [android border](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20border)
2. Идём по первой ссылке: [how to put a border around an android textview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3496269/3212712)
3. Копипастим xml-drawable фон

   ```
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
      <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
      <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#4fa5d5"/>
   </shape>
   ```
4. Назначаем его к-л вьюхе:

   ```
   <Button android:text="Some text" android:background="@drawable/back"/>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

я так сделал надеюсь тебе подойдёт
style="@style/Widget.Material3.Button.IconButton.Outlined"

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iX3vEnTifB0

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/879437)